# Convert NSDate to mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate

I know this question is similar to others asked, but I can't find where my code is going wrong. I am trying to convert the current date into a mm/dd/yyyy format. Here is what I am using:

```
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc]init];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"mm/dd/yyyy"];

NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

The problem is the month. Every time I run this code, the month is different. For example the first time my date was 32/11/2012, and I just ran it and it was 55/11/2012.

Is there a reason why this would keep changing? The days and years appear to be fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Check the case:

`mm` means minutes

`MM` means months

So your code should probably read

```
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc]init];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

Comment: +1 Beat me. Here's the link to [the spec](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns).